# dockerd[1455]: time="2017-12-18T19:08:30.299677811+03:00" level=error msg="stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo"

Tags: docker

I'm calling host docker command line utility from inside of docker container on Ubunty via making it available inside container with volume by passing the host binaries, lib and unix socket when calling docker run as volumes like that:

```
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \ 
  -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker \ 
  -v /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7
```

Then inside container I'm calling:

```
docker run --rm - --hostname registrator_notificator_222444 -it -P -d \
  -e CONSUL_1=172.17.0.3:8301 mycontainername:5043/app/myappname /etc
```

and then getting the error:

> dockerd[1455]: time="2017-12-18T19:08:30.299677811+03:00" level=error msg="stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo"

What is fifo said in the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with wrong last parameter in the docker run call:

docker run  --rm --hostname registrator_notificator_222444 -it -P -d  -e CONSUL_1=172.17.0.3:8301 mycontainername:5043/app/myappname **/etc**

is was a typo and had no sence; it was leading for such error

Comment: getting same error after 30 -40 mins running the container.